# Req.body is Empty in Node Js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs, body-parser

In my Node application I am trying to view request.body object to check for elements that are coming inside of it but `console.log(req.body)` revels that its empty. Here are my files.

`app.js` file below

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var nationalPark = require("./models/NationalParks");



//config
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/National_Parks', {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true}).catch(function(reason){
    console.log('Unable to connect to the mongodb instance. Error: ', reason);
});
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
var bod = require("body-parser");
app.use(bod.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.use(bod.json());


app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/resources'));


//Routes
app.get("/",function(req,res){
    nationalPark.find({},function(err,nationalParks){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }else{

            res.render("home",{nationalParks:nationalParks});
        }
    })

});

app.get("/home",function(req,res){
    nationalPark.find({},function(err,nationalParks){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }else{
            console.log(nationalParks);
            res.render("home",{nationalParks:nationalParks});
        }
    })
});

app.get("/login",function(req,res){
    res.render("login");
});
app.get("/signup",function(req,res){
    res.render("signup");
});
app.get("/logout",function(req,res){
    res.render("home");
});

app.get("/NationalPark",function(req,res){
    console.log(park.park)
 res.render("NationalPark",{park:park.park});
});

app.post("/NationalPark",function(req,res){

      console.log(req.body);
    res.render("NationalPark");
});
app.get("/post",function(req,res){
    res.render("post");
});
app.get("/post-display",function(req,res){
    res.render("post-display");
});
app.get("/profile",function(req,res){
    res.render("profile");
});

//listening port
app.listen(3000,function(){
    console.log("Server started");
});
```

Here is my `home.ejs`  file

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/national-parks.css">


  </head>
  <body>


        <div class="container" id="headContainer">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-2">
              <nav class="nav flex-column">
                <a class="nav-link active text-white" href="/login">Login</a>
                <a class="nav-link active text-white" href="/signup">Sign Up</a>
                <a class="nav-link active text-white" href="/logout">Logout</a>
              </nav>
            </div>

            <div class="col-10" id="heading">
              <h1 class="display-3">National Parks Observer</h1>
              <p class="lead">Site Dedicated to Indian National Parks</p>
             </div>


         </div>
        </div>




        <div class="container" id="postings">

         <%  var r=Math.round(nationalParks.length/3); %>
         <% var x = 1; %>
         <% var elementCount = 3; %>
         <% var constant = 3; %>
         <% var start=0; %>
         <% while(x<=r){ %>
          <div class="row">

           <% for(var k=start;k<elementCount;k++){ %>

            <div class="col-4">
              <div class="card">

               <form method="POST" action="/NationalPark">  
                <img class="card-img-top" src=<%=nationalParks[k].imageurl %> alt="Card image cap">


                <h5 class="card-title" name="parktitle" id="title"><%=nationalParks[k].nationalPark %></h5>

                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"">View Page</button>

                </form> 

              </div>
           </div>

           <% } %>
           <%  start=start+constant; %>
           <%   elementCount=Math.min(elementCount+constant,nationalParks.length); %>


          </div>

          <% x++; }  %>










        </div>


        <br>
        <br>
        <br>



    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="/javascript/national-park.js"></script>     

  </body>
</html>
```

at following post method in `app.js`

```
app.post("/NationalPark",function(req,res){

      console.log(req.body);
    res.render("NationalPark");
});
```

`console.log(req.body)` simply prints `{}`

Why is it happening, am I missing something? Will deeply appreciate your help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This would depend on what are you passing the body when you did the POST request. This part here is just a listener, you need to send data from where you call the endpoint

Comment: You don't need to include `body-parser` for your code. Express has default functionality for your use cases. You can use `app.use(express.json());` and `app.use(express.urlencoded());`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your form, the excerpt below has no `<input />` elements.

```
<form method="POST" action="/NationalPark">  
                <img class="card-img-top" src=<%=nationalParks[k].imageurl %> alt="Card image cap">


                <h5 class="card-title" name="parktitle" id="title"><%=nationalParks[k].nationalPark %></h5>

                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"">View Page</button>

                </form>
```

So no data is posted back to the app.

Adding an input element example

```
<Input type="hidden" name="park_name" value=<%=nationalParks[k].nationalPark %> />
```

In your form would make the attribute `req.body.park_name` available in app.js

Comment: that's a useful tool.Thanks.